# Python kivy position of label doesnt work

Tags: python, kivy

im writing a program on python kivy. And i have a problem. Why is two labels so far apart. I need labels will be 3 pixels apart. When u start program press 'Check words'. And next question is how can i add definite line from file to label. So that when new words appear in the file, they are added to the new Label

```
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set("graphics", "resizable", 0)
Config.set("graphics", "width", 300)
Config.set("graphics", "height", 600)

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager, SlideTransition
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_file('''
<EngAppMenu>:
    background_normal: ''
    background_color: (43/255, 61/255, 91/255, 1)
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.95, 'center_x': 0.5}
        spacing: 10
        size_hint: 0.72, 0.18
        Button:
            text: "Check words"
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: (26/255, 45/255, 64/255, 1)
            #size_hint: 0.08, 0.67
            #size: 200, 50
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'checkwords'
        Button:
            text: "Add words"
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: (26/255, 45/255, 64/255, 1)
            #size_hint: 0.67, 0.08
            #size: 200, 50
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'addwords'



<AddWordsMenu>:
    background_normal: ''
    background_color: (43/255, 61/255, 91/255, 1)
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.95, 'center_x': 0.5}
        spacing: 8
        size_hint: 0.8, 0.2

        TextInput:
            multiline: False
            hint_text: "Original word"
            id: eng_words
            on_text_validate:
                translation_words.focus=True

        TextInput:
            multiline: False
            hint_text: "Translation word"
            id: translation_words
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.73, 'center_x': 0.5}
        spacing: 8
        size_hint: 0.8, 0.08
        Button:
            text: "Save"
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: (26/255, 45/255, 64/255, 1)
            on_press:
                app.save(eng_words.text, translation_words.text)
                eng_words.text = ""
                translation_words.text = ""

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.1, 'center_x': 0.5}
        spacing: 8
        size_hint: 0.8, 0.07
        Button:
            text: "Menu"
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: (26/255, 45/255, 64/255, 1)
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = 'menu'



<CheckWordsMenu>:
    background_normal: ''
    background_color: (43/255, 61/255, 91/255, 1)
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.95, 'center_x': 0.5}
        spacing: 8
        size_hint: 0.8, 0.07
        Button:
            text: "Menu"
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: (26/255, 45/255, 64/255, 1)
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.93, 'center_x': 0.4}
        spacing: 3
        size_hint: 0.8, 0.01
        halign: 'left'
        valign: 'center'
        Label:
            id: text1
            text: "Hello"
            texture_size: 'size'
            size_hint: None, None
        Label:
            id: text2
            text: "Hello2"
            texture_size: 'size'
            size_hint: None, None




''')

class EngAppMenu(Screen, GridLayout):
    pass

class AddWordsMenu(Screen, GridLayout):
    pass

class CheckWordsMenu(Screen, GridLayout):
    pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(EngAppMenu(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(AddWordsMenu(name="addwords"))
sm.add_widget(CheckWordsMenu(name="checkwords"))

class EngApp(App):

    def build(self):

        return sm

    def save(self, engw, trnw):
        eng = open('englishwords.txt','a', encoding='utf_8')
        eng.write(engw + "\n")
        eng.close()

        trn = open('translationwords.txt','a', encoding='utf_8')
        trn.write(trnw + "\n")
        trn.close()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    EngApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
texture_size: 'size'
```

from your labels, and add:

```
height: self.texture_size[1]
```

to the same two `Labels`.

Setting `texture_size` to a string will not work, since `texture_size` is a list of height and width. Setting `height` to `self.texture_size[1]` forces the `Label` to a `height` that is just large enough to contain the text. Note that you will need to better position the containing `GridLayout`.

Comment: Thank u. How can i make the letters add to the right side and the words don't move on the left side

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but you can submit a new question about that.